# OSError using Transformers on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, huggingface-transformers

I created code in python to summarize news articles and the code works on both my laptop as well as after creating a Docker image for it.

```
try:
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    import base64
    import re
    from transformers import BartForConditionalGeneration, BartTokenizer, BartConfig
    import json
except Exception as e:
    print("Error imports : {} ".format(e))

def lambda_handler(event=None, context=None):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

    url = 'https://news.google.com/news/rss'
    client = urlopen(url)
    xml_page = client.read()
    client.close()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_page, 'xml')

    contents = soup.find_all("item")

    encoded_links = []
    headlines = []
    dates = []

    for news in contents:
        if "youtube.com" in str(news.source):
            continue
        encoded_links.append(news.link.text)
        headlines.append(news.title.text)
        dates.append(news.pubDate.text)

    encoded_links = encoded_links[:15]
    headlines = headlines[:15]
    dates = dates[:15]

    decoded_links = []

    for link in encoded_links:
        coded = link[44:-5]
        while True:
            try:
                url = base64.b64decode(coded)
                break
            except:
                coded += "a"
        url = str(base64.b64decode(coded))

        strip1 = re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", url).group("url")
        strip2 = stripped = strip1.split('$', 1)[0]
        strip3 = stripped = strip2.split('\\', 1)[0]
        decoded_links.append(strip3)

    summarized_texts = []

    tokenizer = BartTokenizer.from_pretrained('facebook/bart-large-cnn')
    model=BartForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained('facebook/bart-large-cnn')

    for link in decoded_links:
        try:
            new_page = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
        except:
            continue
        new_soup  = BeautifulSoup(new_page.text, 'lxml')
        
        text = ""
        paragraphs = new_soup.find_all("p")
        for p in paragraphs:
            text += p.text

        inputs = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus([text],return_tensors='pt', truncation=True, max_length=1024)
        summary_ids = model.generate(inputs['input_ids'], early_stopping=True)

        bart_summary = tokenizer.decode(summary_ids[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

        summarized_texts.append(bart_summary)
        print(bart_summary)


    print("Success,", len(summarized_texts), "summaries created.")

    returned = [{'headline': title, 'date': date, 'summary': summarized} for title, date, summarized in zip(headlines, dates, summarized_texts)]

    json_summaries = json.dumps(returned)

    return json_summaries
```

And my Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN python -m nltk.downloader punkt
COPY app.py ./

CMD ["app.lambda_handler"]
```

But when I upload the docker image to aws ecr and use that in lambda, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user1051'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/app.py", line 58, in lambda_handler
    tokenizer = BartTokenizer.from_pretrained('facebook/bart-large-cnn')
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py", line 1744, in from_pretrained
    resolved_vocab_files[file_id] = cached_path(
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/utils/hub.py", line 284, in cached_path
    output_path = get_from_cache(
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/utils/hub.py", line 486, in get_from_cache
    os.makedirs(cache_dir, exist_ok=True)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 215, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 215, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 215, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 225, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
```

And I can't seem to figure out what this error is for. I can see that the error has to do with the Transformers library, but since the code ran in a docker image I think that the issue isn't due to any missing libraries or files.

Answer (score 1):

The error has nothing to do with Transformers library. It says

```
[ERROR] OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user1051'
```

The problem is, as the error says, you can only write/download something inside lambda into the /tmp directory. It is a temporary storage (The default size is 512mb but you can increase it with paying more)

You can define cache directories of pre-trained models:

```
tokenizer = BartTokenizer.from_pretrained('facebook/bart-large-cnn', cache_dir="/tmp/")
model=BartForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained('facebook/bart-large-cnn',cache_dir="/tmp/")
```

Comment: Updated the post to add the dockerfile. I didn't try to write anything into the /home file. Should I still try adding the tmp into the folder?

Comment: from_pretrained > written into a some directory/cache.

Comment: That did help but I'm now running into a different error. It has to do with loading the model on lambda. https://stackoverflow.com/q/73452601/16451065